# Why is TFS 2015 Agent still looking for Deleted Workspace?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I deleted some workspaces used by my vNext Build Agents because I was getting the error that the folder was already in use. This was happening with a lot of my folders. Now my build agent is looking for the folder I deleted. The actual error message is

> "The workspace ws_c0007cd6_11;Project Build Service does not exist."

I was able to circumvent this problem once by recreating the workspace. I don't want to do this for every missing workspace, and it doesn't seem to always work anyway. Is there a way I can get my Build Agents to stop looking for old work spaces and start creating new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hit the same problems but the only other option we found to work was to delete the agent and reconfigure.  Sorry.

Comment: This wasn't a great experience. I had to: 1. Delete the agent in TFS Settings, 2. Delete all the directories under the Agent's _work directory, which required removing a work space with Visual Studio, because it had a lock on the directory, 3. Reconfiguring with NETWORK SERVICE as the account. 4. (to be done) Have IT log the service account into services.msc, because they won't let me know the password. Thanks a lot though, @chief7